# Hello World in EmberJs Error

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I am writing first program in **EmberJs** as `"Hello World"` printing, but getting errors. Can someone help me out?

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/2.7.0/ember.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      App = Ember.Application.create();
      App.Router.map(function() {
        this.resource('index', { path: '/' }, function() {});
        this.resource('hi', { path: '/hi' }, function() {});
      });
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='index'>
      <p>index!</p>
      <p>{{#linkTo hi}}hi{{/linkTo}}</p>
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='hi'>
      hello world!
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**ERROR**

[image]

Comment: Since Ember 2, the preferred way to develop an Ember application is to use [ember-cli](https://ember-cli.com/) workflow, which prevents this kind of errors by including all necessary stuff to build your project.

[Tom Dale](http://stackoverflow.com/users/926126/tom-dale) mentions this in [The Road to Ember 2.0 RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15).

I think you should take a look at the [Ember quick start](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/getting-started/quick-start/) for your first steps in the Ember environment, it covers everything for a _Hello world_ application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include ember-template-compiler instead of handlebars:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/2.7.0/ember.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/2.7.0/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
```

You also can't use `linkTo` helper because it's deprecated and that's why you get another error. Here's [working fiddle.](http://jsbin.com/cujobozesa/edit?html,jsa,output)

Comment: Still getting error: "ember.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isHelperInstance' of undefined".Can you share working fiddle?